# What are some nice ways to reverse a nested hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

Suppose we have

```
b = {"b"=>"c"}
```

By doing `b.invert`we can easily obtain the result of

```
{"c"=>"b"}
```

Thats when I thought of trying something pretty cool. Suppose we have

```
a = {"a"=>{"b"=>"c"}}
```

Whats a fairly efficient way to make this `{{"c"=>"b"}=>"a"}` (Here we reverse the most inner `hash` and work our way out)

Of course it would be best to extend this to `n` amount of hashes within each other. I've been looking for some other questions similar but haven't found any.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a recursive method for inverting the keys of the hash (and values, if desired). For example:

```
hsh = {{"c"=>"b"}=>"a"}
def recursive_invert(hsh)
    hsh.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), inverted_hsh|
        if k.is_a? Hash
            k = recursive_invert(k)
        end
        inverted_hsh[v] = k 
    end
end
recursive_invert(hsh) # {"a"=>{"b"=>"c"}}
```

Comment: Very nice. A recursive solution was indeed something I was trying on my own. +1. Lets see what other rubyists can come up with :)

Comment: This will not work in the other direction as requested in the OP. `{"a"=>{"b"=>"c"}}` converted to `{{"c"=>"b"}=>"a"}`

Comment: @engineersmnky It will if values of the hash are inverted too, as mentioned (and as implemented in your answer).

Comment: Hi, I am new to ruby and found this question interesting. What does it mean when we put (k,v) in .each_with_object, I thought it two arguents, how do we know what k and v mean here?

Answer (score 4):

Here's A recursive solution that will work in both directions.

```
def deep_invert(h)
    h.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),obj|
        k = deep_invert(k) if k.is_a?(Hash)
        v = deep_invert(v) if v.is_a?(Hash)
        obj[v] = k
    end
end
```

Example:

```
a = {"a"=>{"b"=>"c"}}
deep_invert(a) 
#=> {{"c"=>"b"}=>"a"}
deep_invert(deep_invert(a)) == a 
#=> true
```